# How to find two successive and same values in a Stream?

Tags: scala, stream, duplicates, return, scala-streams

How can I find two successive and same values in a `Stream` and return this "duplicate-value":

```
def succ: Stream[Int] => Int = str => ...
```

For instance `Stream(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2)` would result in `5`.

How would one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zipping the stream with its tail is another way of doing this which seems to handle single element Streams. Empty streams are handled explicitly:

```
def succ: Stream[Int] => Int = {
  case Stream() => 0
  case str =>
    str.zip(str.tail).
    find { case (l, r) => l == r }.
    map { case (x, _) => x }.
    getOrElse(0)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a mix of [`Stream.sliding`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html#sliding(size:Int):Iterator[Repr]) and [`Stream.collectFirst`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html#collectFirst[B](pf:PartialFunction[A,B]):Option[B]):

```
def succ(stream: Stream[Int]): Option[Int] =
  stream.sliding(2).collectFirst { case Stream(x, y) if x == y => x }
```

which produces:

```
Stream(1, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 2, 2)
  .sliding(2) // Stream(Stream(1, 2), Stream(2, 4), Stream(4, 3), ...
  .collectFirst { case Stream(x, y) if x == y => x } // Some(5)
```

or `None` if no successive elements share the same value.

---

As per your comment, in order to return `0` instead of `None` when no successive elements share the same value, you can apply `.getOrElse(0)` at the end of the pipeline:

```
def succ(stream: Stream[Int]): Int =
  stream.sliding(2).collectFirst { case Stream(x, y) if x == y => x }.getOrElse(0)
```

Comment: If there are no successive values it returns 0. f there is such a value it should return it directly.

Answer (score 0):

How about using simple recursion?

```
def succ: Stream[Int] => Int = {
  def rec(x: Int, xs: Stream[Int]): Int = {
    if (x == xs.head) x
    else rec(xs.head, xs.tail)
  }

  (str: Stream[Int]) => rec(str.head, str.tail)
}
```

This doesn't work if there are no subsequent duplicates found, for that you'll have to change your return type to `Option[Int]` and add some additional checks.